# Cut in sed issue, unknown option to s

Tags: sed, cut, command-substitution

```
echo $HOME $var
/home/user abc
```

My variables.

```
echo $HOME$var | sed "s/$(echo $HOME$var | cut -c 3)/ello/g"
/hellome/userabc
```

This works as expected.

```
echo $HOME$var | sed "s/$(echo $HOME$var | cut -c 3-)/ello/g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'
```

Adding the range "3 to the end" produces failure. The subexpression has no problem when isolated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Replace text so it says "hello".

Comment: change delimiter from `/` to any character that doesn't occur in your input.. for ex: `#` or `,` or `|` etc